# Explanation on Umbraco Identity plugin

Tags: asp.net-identity, umbraco, umbraco7

Im new to Umbraco and Im trying to follow this guide(link below) to add facebook login to my umbraco site. I got stuck halfway on installation. In step 2, it says

> "You must add these properties to your Member Types:"

https://github.com/Shazwazza/UmbracoIdentity/wiki#installation

When I go to Umbraco Backoffice-->Members-->Member types and add a property I cant only select editors (like TextArea aso). How do I add a property of type
"Security Stamp" as the guide suggest.... and further to the left, the type is "no", what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're reading the instructions wrong:

You need to add a new property to your Member Type with an Alias of `securityStamp` and a type of `Umbraco.Textbox` (you can just use the pre-existing `TextString` control).  The other three columns refer to settings of the new Property.

So you extra property would look something like this:

[image]

In relation to the "Show on profile" and "Member can edit" columns in the guide, you can safely ignore those here.  The "Mandatory" column refers to the "Field is Mandatory" checkbox in the property dialog.

Comment: Great! Thanks a bunch! It seems very obvious now that youve explained it :D